# Porque no se esta aplicando la clase rotate correctamente

Tags: reactjs, tailwind

Estoy haciendo el diseño de un reloj de manecillas digital con react y tailwind, tengo el array numbers que contiene los numeros que se ubican de forma circular, pero dentro de la funcion map al aplicar la clase rotate y usar ${} para asignar valores dinamicos, la clase no se aplica, ya lo intente tambien de la forma rotate-[${num*30}deg] y tampoco funciona, no se que hago mal, Gracias de antemano

```
export default function App() {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

  return (
    <div className=" w-[100%] h-[100vh]  bg-red-900 flex justify-center items-center">
      <div className=" relative  min-w-[400px] min-h-[400px] bg-slate-900 rounded-full ">
        {numbers.map((num, index) => (
          <div
            className={`absolute border w-[100%] h-[100%] rotate-${num*30} `}
            key={index}
          >
            <span className={`flex justify-center text-5xl relative top-2  `} >
              {num}
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: ¿Has definido esas rotaciones en Tailwind?

Comment: He probado el código con React y Tailwind y funciona bien con `rotate-[${num*30}deg]`.